# Values missing in awk

Tags: shell, unix, awk

My Input files :

```
file1
231|35000
234|15000
242|60000
254|12313
345|50000
435|24300

file2
1|madhan|retl|231|tcs
2|vaisakh|retl|234|tcs
4|sam|ins|242|infy
5|tina|bfs|254|tcs
3|ram|bfs|345|infy
6|subbu|bfs|435|infy
```

Ouput :
Trying to get

```
col1 , col2  of file1 and col2 of file2 based on common column(col1 of file1 and col4 of file2)
```

My code :

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="|";} NR==FNR{a[$1] = $2;next} ($4 in a) {print $2 "|" $4 "|" a[$1]} ' file_1 file_2
```

O/p i got:

```
madhan|231|
vaisakh|234|
sam|242|
tina|254|
ram|345|
subbu|435|
```

Can you help why last col is coming as spaces

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
join -t '|' -1 1 -2 4 file1 file2 | awk -F'|' '{print $1 "|" $2 "|" $4}'
```

Join on field 1 from file1 and field 4 on file 2 and extract fields what you need using awk.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
awk -F\| 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$0;next} {for (i in a) if (i==$4) print a[i]"|"$2}' file1 file2
231|35000|madhan
234|15000|vaisakh
242|60000|sam
254|12313|tina
345|50000|ram
435|24300|subbu
```

It store `file1` in array `a` using first field as index.
Then it test index in first file against fourth field in `file2`.
If they are equal, print data from `file1` and second field from `file2`.

Comment: Thanks Jotne.  But if my input files have millions of records, will awk work efficient?

Comment: @Madan `awk` will work but you need to test it to see how long time it takes.

Answer (score 0):

It is coming up blank because the key does not exist in the array. You are storing first column of file1 as key which is 4th column of file2.

```
$ awk '
  BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } 
  NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2; next } 
  ($4 in a) { print $2, $4, a[$4] }
' file1 file2
madhan|231|35000
vaisakh|234|15000
sam|242|60000
tina|254|12313
ram|345|50000
subbu|435|24300
```

If you need the order stated in your requested O/P then

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"}NR==FNR{a[$4]=$2;next} ($1 in a) {print $0, a[$1]}' file2 file1
231|35000|madhan
234|15000|vaisakh
242|60000|sam
254|12313|tina
345|50000|ram
435|24300|subbu
```